# Amazon RDS postgres/mysql vs AMAZON RDS Aurora postgres/mysql DB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have been reading Amazon RDS. Amazon claims RDS Aurora is highly reliability, cost-effective etc etc. But didn’t find supporting case studies or documents for the claim.
Can you help me to understand, what are advantages and disadvantages of AWS RDS postgres/mysql DB and AWS RDS Aurora postgres/mysql DB instances? When to choose Aurora over RDS?

Answer (score 0):

I read Amazon's CTO's blog and he posted a whitepaper on this topic a while back (but after you asked the question): https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/p1041-verbitski.pdf

This was the paper that really helped me understand HOW amazon was getting the redundancy - it has enabled shared data storage between the write and read nodes - and taken some of the concepts of what I'm used to from cassandra on quorum and consistency levels.  It reads at 3 of 6 and writes at 4 of 6.  Data is cross 3 availability zones so that a single AZ failure still allows 4 copies of data.